# Count of number of $3$-digit strings with at least two of $0,1,2$.

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the count of $3$-digit strings with at least two of $0,1,2$.

Well I am getting $432$ as the answer, which I think is way too much.
For starters, I considered that one number of $\{0,1,2\}$ could take any place so $3 \times 3$.  Then any other number (previous number included) would take $3 \cdot 2$ so total rn is $3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 2$, now the last place can be filled by any of the $9$ digit so $\times 9$.

After reducing the repeated numbers ($9 \times 3 \times 2$), which according to me will all be palindromes with these numbers, I got my result.

Looks like I need help here.  If I did anything wrong, I'd be happy to hear your comments.

Comment: The rules are not clear.  There are $3^3=27$ possible strings of length three on the alphabet $\{1,2,3\}$.  Did you mean something else?  I have no idea where your $432$ comes from.

Comment: Are you looking for all three-digit numbers (with digits in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and presumably no leading zero) containing at least two of $1, 2$, and $3$? If so, it's easier to count those numbers containing none or one of those digits and subtract from the total number of three-digit numbers.

Comment: Really sorry, made a small error while writing it.

Comment: Is $14$ considered to contain a zero?

Comment: Yes, 014 is a valid number here.

Comment: Still not quite clear, even with the edit.  Does the string need to have two *distinct* entries from $\{1, 2, 3 \}$, or can you use one of those digits twice?  In other words, are you including $411$ among the strings you’re trying to count?

Comment: For the record, we typically refer to $014$ as a two-digit number even though we chose a representation of it which used three digits and more commonly write it simply as $14$.  If you intend $014$ to be treated as "three"-whatever... I suggest treating these objects you are counting as "three-character numeric strings"

Comment: yes, i meant the same "string" thing but doesn't really makes a difference to the question, does it?

Comment: As for your attempt, you are incorrectly applying some sort of significance to *when* in the process each digit was selected, leading to an overcount.  You are counting "*pick the digit $1$ and place it in first position followed by picking digit $2$ and placing it in the second position etc...*" as a different outcome than "*pick the digit $2$ and place it in second position followed by picking digit $1$ and placing it in the first position etc...*" despite both sequences of choices leading to the same final outcome of $123$

Comment: Yes, that is the issue and i have no idea how to fix that

Comment: The recommendation on how to correctly count this remains the same... find the count of how many are "bad" because they included only one or zero of your desired digits and subtract from the total.  $1000 - 7^3 - 3\cdot 7^2\cdot 3=216$.  Alternatively, if you insist on approaching directly, then first *simultaneously* pick which positions are filled by desired digits and then *from left to right* pick which digits filled each spot.  $3^3 + 3\cdot 3^2\cdot 7=216$

Comment: $7^3$ is the number of bad numbers containing only undesired digits.  $7$ choices for the first undesired digit, $7$ for the second, $7$ for the third, multiplying these together as per rule of product to get the total.  $3\cdot 7^2\cdot 3$ is the number containing only one desired digit.  First, choose the position of the desired digit in 3 ways.  Then, choose the leftmost undesired digit in $7$ ways, choose the rightmost undesired digit in another $7$ ways, and then choose the desired digit in $3$ ways.  Applying rule of product to combine these together for a count.

Comment: @JMoravitz See below for an answer.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $1000$ possible strings with no constraints whatsoever.  Of those, $7^3=343$ use none of the digits $\{0, 1, 2 \}$.

To count the strings that have an entry from $\{0, 1, 2 \}$ in exactly one position, note that we have $3$ choices of that position, $3$ choices from among $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ to fill that position, and $7^2=49$ choices to fill the remaining positions, for a total of $9 \cdot 49=441$ additional "bad" strings.

Thus, there are $1000-(343+441)=216$ "good" strings.

**Edit**:  As noted by fleablood in an answer and by JMoravitz in a comment, you can use the same method of analysis to count the "good" strings directly.  There are $3^3=27$ strings that fill all three positions from the set $\{0, 1, 2\}$.

To count the strings that have an entry from $\{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 \}$ in exactly one position (and therefore entries from $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ in exactly two positions), note that we have $3$ choices of that position, $7$ choices from among $\{ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 \}$ to fill that position, and $3^2=9$ choices to fill the remaining positions for a total of $3 \cdot 7 \cdot 9 =189$ additional "good" strings.

Thus, there are $27+189 = 216$ good strings.

Comment: Crisply answered +1

Answer (score 1):

So going over your method.

> i considered that one number of {0,1,2} could take any place so 3×3

If I understand you correctly your nine options are $0xx, x0x, xx0; 1xx,x1x,xx1; 2xx,x2x,xx2$.  Correct.  You are choosing the value of one of the numbers and choosing its position.

> Then any other number (previous number included) would take 3×2 so total rn is 3×3×3×2

Now you are double counting.  If we mark the first chosen number in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ and the second in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$.  Choosing first $1$ for position $3$ and $2$ for position $1$; that is:  $\color{red}2x\color{green}1$.  But if you chose first the $2$ for position $1$ and then $1$ for positon $3$ to get $\color{green}2x\color{red}1$ you are counting these as different choices.

As the order of the choices doesn't matter you must divide by $2$ to have $\frac{3\times 3\times 3\times 2}2=3\times 3\times 3$.

> now the last place can be filled by any of the 9 digit so ×9

But now you are still over counting.  If third digit is $0,1,2$ then .... well let's put the first two digits in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ and the third in $\color{purple}{\text{purple}}$ we have $\color{blue}{32}\color{purple}3$ and $\color{blue}3\color{purple}2\color{blue}3$ and $\color{purple}3\color{blue}{23}$ counting as three different numbers.

To handle this we mus consider for the $3$ cases were the third digit is $0,1$ or $2$ we must divide by the $3$ places the third digit can be.  So $(3\times3\times 3)\times \frac 33 = 3\times 3\times 3$.

Then for the $7$ cases where the third digit is not $0,1,2$ you aren't over counting so we have $3\times 3\times 3\times 7$.

Adding those together we have $3\times 3\times 3 + 3\times 3\times 3\times 3 = 216$.

.....

Although it might be better to make a simpler model.

IMO I'd do...

There are two cases.  Two of the three digits are $0,1,2$ and the third isn't.  Or all three of the three digits are $0,1,2$.

If all three of the digits are $0,1,2$ then for each position there are $3$ choices so the number ways is $choice^{positions} = 3^3 = 27$ (or $3\times 3\times 3$ if you prefer.

If one of the digits is not $0,1,$ or $2$ then there are $3$ choices for that position.  And there are $7$ choices for it's value. $(3\times 7)$.  Then for the remaining $2$ position there are $3$ choices for each value so $(3\times 7)\times 3^2$.

So the total number is $(3\times 3\times 3) + (3\times 7)\times(3\times 3) = 216$.

=====

Edit:  Oh.  Robert Shore's method of elimination is a good model too.  Maybe even easier.  Number of at least two = All numbers - Those with fewer than two = All number - (Those with none + those with exactly one).  Can't argue with that and those are relatively easy values to calculate.

I do find it interesting when numbers combine in strange ways to get same result.

$3^3 + 3\times 7\times 3^2 = 10^3 -(7^3 + 3\times 3\times 7^2)$.

Who'd have thunk it.

Comment: @RobertShore Good Lord!  I'm becoming as blind as a bat in my old age!  Sorry.  Will fix.

Comment: "that's Robert Shore, not Robert Stone" and it certainly isn't Robert**s** Stone!  Somedays it's not worth getting out of bed.